# How to automate the process "rotation of keys in Azure Key Vault"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-keyvault, azure-automation

Am working on the rotation of keys in Azure Key Vault through Azure Automation. I did it by using Azure Runbooks in azure automation successfully. But, I want to get an alert of the keys which is going to expire before expired and then run my runbook to rotation of those keys automatically. The entire process to be done automatically with the help of azure automation and VSTS-Build. Please, give me some suggestions for this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can apply a schedule for the runbook back directly: [Key rotation using Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-key-rotation-log-monitoring#key-rotation-using-azure-automation)

Secondly, with VSTS, you can schedule build to do it through PowerShell

[A blog that can help you: Expiry Notification for Azure Key Vault Keys and Secrets](http://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/expiry-notification-for-azure-key-vault-keys-and-secrets/)