# Handling key rotation in azure function app which pulls latest secret version from key vault

Tags: azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I fetch the secrets from the key vault in Azure functions by setting the property in Configuration using:

`@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/)`

I don't use the secret version in the above setting so that it pulls the latest secret version whenever key rotation happens.

As per Azure documentation -
`If a version is not specified in the reference, then the app will use the latest version that exists in Key Vault. When newer versions become available, such as with a rotation event, **the app will automatically update and begin using the latest version within one day**. Any configuration changes made to the app will cause an immediate update to the latest versions of all referenced secrets.`

In the production environment, this one-day lag will cause an impact. Is there any other way to get the latest secret version without the lag and also without manually updating the configuration setting with the latest secret version? I also don't want to stop and start the function app to get the secret synced up.

I tried using the below piece of code but seems it pulls the same result as the above "@Microsoft.KeyVault", which means the old secret version. Is it due to the caching?

```
string kvUri = $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net";
SecretClient client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
Azure.Response<KeyVaultSecret> secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
```

Answer (score 1):

We have tested in our environment Based on the repro , below are the observations.

> In the production environment, this one-day lag will cause an impact. Is there any other way to get the latest secret version without the lag and also without manually updating the configuration setting with the latest secret version? I also don't want to stop and start the function app to get the secret synced up.

if you want to rotate the secret using the functions app immediately when the secret got expired  you need to perform management operation like (update , enabling & disabling of function ,restart the function app) if not you need to wait  as mentioned in the [azure documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references#rotation)

> I tried using the below piece of code but seems it pulls the same
> result as the above "@Microsoft.KeyVault", which means the old secret
> version. Is it due to the caching?

we are able to pull the latest version of secret from key vault using the powershell cmdlet irrespective of the secret expiry date
Below is the command :

```
$secret= (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName <keyvaultname> -Name <secretName> -AsPlainText)
```

Here is the reference thread for rotation azure key vaults secrets automatically using [powershell & runbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49979739/how-to-automate-the-process-rotation-of-keys-in-azure-key-vault)

Comment: Thank you for sharing the details. The first option is not reliable in my scenario as I don't want to restart the Azure function App. I will check the second option, but I think there was some confusion on the rotation part. There is no rotation that I have to do from the Azure function, I just need to get the latest secrets from the key vault.